# Is there a way to have something like ">" of awk in R?

Tags: r

In awk, it is convenient to print to a file using ">". Awk knows if it is the same file, it will not reopen the file. The syntax is quite simple

```
print "1" >  "file1.txt"
print "2" >  "file2.txt"
print "3" >  "file1.txt"
```

But in R, it seems to be quite complicated, I probably can do it with `sink()`, but it doesn't keep the files open. It merely appends to the file. This is unacceptable when one needs to switch between writes to multiple files.

Also, it is quite verbose to write rows in a data.frame (one raw at a time) to the file. I am not sure this can be easily done in R either.

Does anybody know if there is any equivalent but not combersome solution in R?

P.S. write.table's append = TRUE is not the same as awk's ">". The R's append is the same as opening the file and append to it. But awk's ">" does not close the file.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on your exact use case and why opening and closing files is troublesome?

Comment: You can probably create many file connections via the `file` command and there's an option to open them - assign them either to elements of the list or a set of variables, and you'll be able to use the correct one in `cat` or whatever you want to use to output. But a more idiomatic way would be to index the rows of the dataframe you want to write to one file, and `write.table(df[is_odd,], file="odd_rows.txt")` etc

Comment: Are you looking for `write.table`'s `append = TRUE` setting?

Comment: Sending the output of one program to a file is a function of the *shell* (e.g., bash, sh, csh, ksh, zsk), not `awk`. In fact, `awk` likely knows that the output is not going to a terminal, but otherwise it does not know definitively that the output is going to a file or being piped to another program. As to R being problematic switching between multiple files ... I've not seen anything that suggests this should be a concern. Do you see performance problems? (Writing frame rows to a file? What about `write.csv` or `write.table`, asGavin and Roland suggested?)

Comment: What about `writeLines()`? You can open the connection first with `file()` and then `close()` it when done. You can probably use this with the `magrittr` `%>%` as well so that `text %>% writeLines(con = the_connection)`.